# How to stop PHP source from being printed to my browser?

Tags: php

I just downloaded this "PHP Code Snippet Library" scrpt from http://www.sourceforge.net/projects/php-csl/ , when I try to run it from my local dev server, all the PHP on every page is output as PHP code, instead of compiling and running the code it seems to show the source of the PHP to the screen.  I have never had this happen before, how can I fix this or what cause this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only reason i can think of that that would happen would be if PHP wasnt installed or if the code was using short tags and they arent enabled on your box.

Comment: it does seem to be using short tags like this <? and I just installed the latest PHP version yesterday so that is probably it then

Comment: Wow theyre really using shortags in a publicly avialable OSS project... SHAME on them.

Comment: that worked, thanks this is a really amazing script too glad I could get it working =)

Comment: Yeah is kind of sad but I believe this is a pretty old script

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
Before reading this post, I'm assuming that...
1. Your test php script has the proper file extension (filename.php)
2. Your test php script isn't using short tags, the abbreviated method, of entering into php ("

You need to make sure the php module is installed and working before you push your website to production. [b]If you're seeing the php code as text in the browser, php is not installed properly[/b]. If the php module for apache isn't enabled apache won't know how to handle php files and will return the php file as plain text.